# Bokeh Tap tool as trigger callback for different figure

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh, tap

I am trying to use the taptool indices to trigger a callback to another plot/figure. 
I adapted my data to fit few examples I have found online as I suck in JS. 
I have been stuck for a good while, so any help would be very helpful. I tried to simply the code and unfortunately I can not share the data, but I believe that the code below it is very straightforward.
I am getting a warning that a warning for this line of code below:

```
wP.select(tap).callback = CustomJS(args = {'week': wP, 'yCol': yCol}, code = code)
```

> 'generator' object has no attribute 'callback'

```
df = YearlyDF_var('Precipitation', 'median')
y = 2020


p1 = figure(match_aspect=True, x_axis_location = None, y_axis_location = None, title='Kalimantan Central',
        tools = 'pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset, save, tap', title_location='below', toolbar_location='above',
       plot_height=550)

src = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

for1 = PrintfTickFormatter(format='%0.0f mm')

p1.image_url(url=['BaritoLine3.png'], x=114.368, y=-1.97, w=1.1, h=3.04, anchor="center")

t2 = p1.circle('x', 'y', line_color='black', size=30, alpha=.7, line_width=.5, color='c', muted_alpha=0.3, source=src)

p1.add_layout(t2)
    
hvF = HoverTool()
hvF.tooltips=[('Collection', '@Location'), ('', '@2020{0.00 a} mm')]

p1.add_tools(hvF)
p1.grid.grid_line_color=None
p1.outline_line_color=None


p1.title.text_font_style = 'bold'
p1.title.text_font_size = '25px'
p1.title.text_color = Viridis[11][3]
p1.title.align = 'center'

p1.toolbar.autohide = True


df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = dfW1.iloc[dfW1.index.get_level_values('yearRaw') == 2020][['Precipitation']]
#dfY = df[[str(var)]]

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2[['week', 'Muara_Teweh', 'Muara_Tuhup',  'Puruk_Cahu', 'Taboneo_Anchorage', 'Tarusan', 'Teluk_Siwak', 'Ujung_Rumput']] = None
df2['week'] = sorted(set(df1.index.get_level_values('weekRaw').map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])))
df2.set_index('week', inplace=True)
df2['Muara_Teweh'] = df1.query("Location == 'Muara Teweh'").values
df2['Muara_Tuhup'] = df1.query("Location == 'Muara Tuhup'").values
df2['Puruk_Cahu'] = df1.query("Location == 'Puruk Cahu'").values
df2['Taboneo_Anchorage'] = df1.query("Location == 'Taboneo Anchorage'").values
df2['Tarusan'] = df1.query("Location == 'Tarusan'").values
df2['Teluk_Siwak'] = df1.query("Location == 'Teluk Siwak'").values
df2['Ujung_Rumput'] = df1.query("Location == 'Ujung Rumput'").values


yCol = [df2['Muara_Teweh'].to_numpy(),
              df2['Muara_Tuhup'].to_numpy(),
              df2['Puruk_Cahu'].to_numpy(),
              df2['Taboneo_Anchorage'].to_numpy(),
              df2['Tarusan'].to_numpy(),
              df2['Teluk_Siwak'].to_numpy(),
              df2['Ujung_Rumput'].to_numpy()]

pWeekly = figure(x_range=df2.index.to_list(), plot_height=300, plot_width=700,
                title='Weekly test', tools='pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset', toolbar_location='right')


wP = pWeekly.vbar(x='x', top='y', source=ColumnDataSource({'x': df2.index.to_list(), 'y':yCol[0]}), width=0.5, color=Paired[7][0])
pWeekly.toolbar.autohide = True
pWeekly.grid.grid_line_dash = 'dotted'
pWeekly.grid.grid_line_dash_offset = 5
pWeekly.grid.grid_line_width = 2
pWeekly.outline_line_color=None

pWeekly.axis.major_label_text_font_style = 'bold'
pWeekly.axis.major_label_text_font_size = '11px'
pWeekly.axis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'bold'
pWeekly.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 45
pWeekly.yaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format='%0.0f mm')
pWeekly.y_range.start = round(df2.min().min(), -3)


code = '''if (cb_data.source.selected.indices.length == 1){
            
            var selected_index = cb_data.source.selected.indices[0];
            week.data_source.data['y'] = yCol[selected_index]
            week.data_source.change.emit(); 
          }'''

tap = TapTool(renderers=[t2], behavior='select')
wP.select(tap).callback = CustomJS(args = {'week': wP, 'yCol': yCol}, code = code)



show(column([p1, pWeekly]))
```

Comment: Do you want to use JS? Could be done with server-side.

Comment: @kağanhazalkoçdemir it has to in JS because I will deploy it with Flask. Downside of Bokeh, if you want to go advantage you need to know JS well. I am seriously considering it at this point.

Comment: @kağanhazalkoçdemir would you have an example with a python callback? I will use the server-side, I dont know why I was avoiding it, the setup it's quiet simple.

Comment: if you provide example of data, sure. And what do you want to trigger exactly?